# Create Ticket using Freshdesk api, response is always { “logout”: “success” }

Tags: logout

Well, I have tried every thing mentioned in Fresh-desk API (http://freshdesk.com/api#create_ticket) to create new ticket but with no success.

Even though i am able to create a new ticket from a Curl request, but when i use a browser REST client it says:

```
{
    "logout": "success"
}
```

I have used the following : https://companyname.freshdesk.com/helpdesk/tickets.json

Headers: `Content-type:application/json Authorization:(Basic Authorization using APIKEY:X)`

```
{ "helpdesk_ticket":{ "description":"No ticket is created ...", "subject":"Support needed..", "email":"anything_xyz@gmail.com", "priority":1, "status":2 } }
```

I have tried clearing my browser cache many times. But the issue remains the same. Please someone suggest.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of REST-Client do you use?

I was facing the same problem as I used the REST-Client Postman (=Chrome Browser extension). Clearing the browers cache solved that issue for me.